# Forge Extension when deployed live is not loading due to uncaught Promise

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an `Autodek Forge Extension` called `HandleSelectionExtension`that is conducting some server requests causing it to load slower than the ForgeViewer. The code is effectively a mirror of this tutorial https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/selection

As a result, when hosted online the Extension fails to load giving the following error
`ExtensionManager.js:234 Uncaught (in promise) Extension not found: HandleSelectionExtension. Has it been registered(1)?`

Note that the Extension works fine when locally hosted. The extension also works if I load a separate page of the domain, such as https://sde4demo.herokuapp.com/data and then click the back button

Is there a way of allowing the extension to fully load before launching the viewer?

Live Demo Here: https://sde4demo.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the extension script is loaded (make sure it precedes your code block that depends on it) before you register the extension and only attempt to load the extension either through `loadOptions` or `viewer.loadExtension` after you registered the extension explicitly.

I've tried your live demo but didn't see any error or the extension being loaded?

Comment: Thanks Bryan, in `index.html`, having the `Extension,js` script html block before the `ForgeViewer.js` block solved the problem. Am I right to say that there is an error in the tutorial where the extension is loaded after `ForgeViewer.js` ?
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton

Answer (score 1):

Having the extension load before the viewer solves the problem

```html
<script src="my-awesome-extension.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this is contradictory to the Forge API Guide which states that extensions must be defined after core viewer classes https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/extensions/

```html
<!-- THIS IS INCORRECT AND CAN CAUSE ASNYC LOADING ISSUES -->
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
<script src="my-awesome-extension.js"></script>
```